# Powershell is installed but winrm is not found

Tags: powershell, remote

one of my servers is win 2003 and has powershell 2.0 installed, but I don't see winrm service there and can't thus run "Winrm quickconfig". It says "command not found". As a result, I can't call Invoke-Command to remote machines in my script.

How to resolve this?

**UPDATE:**

I followed instruction in @Ob1lan link, but got below scary message. I don't want to mess up the server so stopped. According to the linked MSDN article, it is like the only method to enable WinRM, but I checked the other win 2003 server. Its Hardware Management feature is not installed either, but WinRM is there. Wonder why...

[image]

Comment: Could you first have a look at the installation procedure ? Check if everything has been done properly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384372(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This command [is not available in Windows Server 2003](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384372(v=vs.85).aspx) :

> Quick Default Configuration Starting with Windows Vista, you can
>   enable the WS-Management protocol on the local computer and set up the
>   default configuration for remote management with the following
>   command: Winrm quickconfig. Windows Server 2003 R2:  The Winrm
>   quickconfig command is not available. For more information about
>   Windows Server 2003 R2 configuration, see Hardware Management
>   Introduction.

Check this article to know [how to manage WinRM in Windows Server 2003](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f550cac0-5344-41cb-8e89-6e5c93236886).

Comment: I have other Win 2003 servers which have WinRM.

Comment: Except the documentation says otherwise.